# How to reload NSTableView data when NSSearchField text changes

Tags: swift, nstableview, nstextfield, nssearchfield

I'm a bit stumped on how to reload a NSTableView's data upon a searchField's text changing. I assumed that I needed to filter the array that the tableView uses to populate itself based upon string matching and the call `tableView.reloadData()` all inside of `controlTextDidChange()` but when I test the code it doesn't work. I'm assuming that this will be a pretty simple fix and most of the info I've found on this topic has been a bit complicated. So I don't know how simple or complicated the solution really is

Here is my `controlTextDidChange()` func:

```
func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
    noteRecords.filter { $0.title.contains(searchField.stringValue) }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

If someone could please explain how to reload the tableViews data using the filtered array upon the searchField's text changing that would be very much appreciated. Also if it's easier to replace the searchField with a plain NSTextField let me know.

**Edit**

here's the func that populates the tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    let note = allRecords[row]
    let cellIdentifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "NoteInCloudCell")
    
    if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[0] {
        let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, owner: nil) as? NoteInCloudCell
        cell?.noteTitle.stringValue = note.title
        cell?.cloudID.stringValue = note.cloudID
        return cell
    }
    else { return nil }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second array of the same type as `noteRecords` and name it `allRecords`

Assign the complete set of records to `allRecords` and use `noteRecords` as data source array

Replace `controlTextDidChange` with

```
func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
    let query = searchField.stringValue
    if query.isEmpty {
        noteRecords = allRecords
    } else {
        noteRecords = allRecords.filter { $0.title.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(query)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

A more sophisticated way is a diffable data source.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you mean by using ```noteRecords``` as data source array can you please provide a bit more detail on that part? I've edited the question to show the tableView func that populates the table.

Comment: My suggestion requires two arrays of the same type. Array #1 contains all items and will never be modified. Array #2 works as the data source array in `numberOfRows` and `viewFor:row:` and is populated somewhere at the beginning and while seraching. In your code `allRecords` is the data source array, so use the other array for holding all items.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was having trouble because I was setting noteRecords = allRecords in the wrong spot. Once I set it inside of the Task block where I query all records it worked